# How to get a button's frame in the controller's root view

Tags: ios, frame

In my view controller, I add a container view as the root view's subview. After that I create a button as the container's subview. I want to get the button's frame in the root view. But when I use `button.frame` I got the button's frame related to the container. So, can some one tell me how to get the right frame of the button relate to the controller's root view?

Thanks, waiting for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The method you're looking for is `-[UIView convertRect:fromView:]`.  You can do something like:

```
CGRect frameInRootView = [self.view convertRect:button.frame fromView:self.containerView]
```

There are some related functions too.  You can also convert *to* a view.  Using the `convertRect:toView:` method you can go from the button's bounds to the target view, like:

```
CGRect frameInRootView = [button convertRect:button.bounds toView:self.view]
```

`-[UIView convertRect:fromView:]` converts the input rect from the coordinate system of the receiver to the `fromView` argument to the coordinate system of the receiver.  `-[UIView convertRect:toView:]` goes the other direction.

Comment: Thanks, I have try it. My button real frame's origin is {33,60}, but I got {66, 120}, how to solve it?